# EWS fileAttachment.ContentType always null?

Tags: exchangewebservices

I'm currently working on this windows service that is pulling data from an exchange web service. Everything works like a charm, but i am not able to get the contentType / Mime-type of the mail attachments.

Can anyone point me in the direction where to find the problem?

```
 protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {
        Svc = new ExchangeService(ExchangeVersion.Exchange2010_SP2);
        Svc.Credentials = new WebCredentials("kbatest@xxxx.xx", "kba123test");
        Svc.TraceEnabled = true;
        Svc.TraceFlags = TraceFlags.All;
        Svc.AutodiscoverUrl("kbatest@xxxx.xx", RedirectionUrlValidationCallback);

        streamsubscript = Svc.SubscribeToStreamingNotifications(new FolderId[] { WellKnownFolderName.Inbox }, EventType.NewMail);

        connection = new StreamingSubscriptionConnection(Svc, 30);
        connection.AddSubscription(streamsubscript);
        connection.OnNotificationEvent += OnNotificationEvent;
        connection.OnSubscriptionError += ConnectionOnOnSubscriptionError;
        connection.OnDisconnect += ConnectionOnOnDisconnect;
        connection.Open();
    }

private void OnNotificationEvent(object sender, NotificationEventArgs args)
    {
        foreach (var notification in args.Events)
        {
            if (notification.EventType != EventType.NewMail) continue;

            var itemEvent = (ItemEvent)notification;
            mail = GetMailByID(itemEvent.ItemId.UniqueId);

            List<int> ls = ExtractTicketNumber(mail.Subject);

            if (ls.Count > 0)
            {
                foreach (int i in ls)
                {
                    bool exist = CheckTicketExistance(i);

                    if (exist)
                    {
                        SaveMailToEvent(mail, i);
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                SaveMailToTicket(mail);
            }
        }
    }   


 private void SaveMailToEvent(EmailMessage mail, int ticketId)
    {
        string[] mailAddr = mail.From.Address.Split(new char[] { '@' });
        string user = mailAddr[0].ToUpper();
        var eventId = 0;

        using (var conn = new SqlConnection(connectionStr))
        {
            conn.Open();
             eventId = conn.Query<int>("INSERT INTO THGITTicketEvents (EventStatus, CreatedBy, Comment, RefTicketRecID, FileAttached)" +
                        "Values(@EventStatus, @CreatedBy, @Comment, @RefTicketRecID, @FileAttached)" +
                        "SELECT CAST( @@IDENTITY AS int)",
                         new
                         {
                             EventStatus = 9,
                             CreatedBy = user,
                             Comment = mail.Body.Text,
                             RefTicketRecID = ticketId,
                             FileAttached = (mail.HasAttachments) ? 1 : 0
                         }).Single();
        }

        if (mail.HasAttachments)
        {
            using (var conn = new SqlConnection(connectionStr))
            {
                conn.Open();

                foreach (var i in mail.Attachments)
                {
                    FileAttachment fileAttachment = i as FileAttachment;
                    if (fileAttachment != null)
                    {
                        fileAttachment.Load();
                        string test = fileAttachment.ContentType;
                        conn.Query("INSERT INTO THGITAttachments (FileContent, CreatedBy, FileName, RefEventRecID, MimeType)" +
                                   "Values(@FileContent, @CreatedBy, @FileName, @RefEventRecID, @MimeType)",
                            new
                            {
                                FileContent = fileAttachment.Content,
                                CreatedBy = user,
                                FileName = fileAttachment.Name,
                                RefEventRecID = eventId,
                                MimeType = fileAttachment.ContentType,
                            });
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check with [EWSEditor](http://ewseditor.codeplex.com) to see if the attachments actually have that property set.

Comment: i checked with EWSEditer and the property set is present on all attached files. Nice little tool by the way! :-)

Comment: Ok. If your code isn't seeing it, you might want to enable tracing and see what kind of response is coming back from the server. From what I can see your code should work.

Comment: I tried tracing both requests and responses, but only the request seems to contain signs of the contentType. I also found out that if sending mails from external sources such as outlook webmail, gmail the contentType seems to work fine. But sending from one mail account to another "hosted" on the same exchange server does not display any contentType.